# Unable to play DVD movies

Tags: 13.10, upgrade, video, vlc, dvd

Since upgrading from Ubuntu 10.10 to 12 and then to 13, I've got a problem with playing movies form DVD's. When I was using 10.10 version everything was fine, and I didn't have any problems with this issue. I am still using the same notebook with the same drive. DVDs with data are working fine.

I followed all the instructions posted here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs 
That means that I've got installed current version of libdvdcss (I installed it by restricted-estras, but also alon). After alone installation I executed s`udo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh`. Because VLC and MPlayer were still unable to play DVDs, I installed regionset package. Than I checked my regionset (and change it from 2 to 2, to be absolutely sure). After those steps DVDs are still not playable. I tried playing movies with and without enabled menus. I also chmod 660 dev/sr0 and dev/cdrom, and than chgrp them.

Nothing has worked for me and DVDs are stil unplayable.

When /dvd/sr0 is set VLC gives this:

```
   libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 4.2.0
    libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.13 for DVD access
    libdvdread: Could not open /dev/sr0 with libdvdcss.
    libdvdread: Can't open /dev/sr0 for reading
    libdvdnav: vm: failed to open/read the DVD
    libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.13 for DVD access
    libdvdread: Could not open /dev/sr0 with libdvdcss.
    libdvdread: Can't open /dev/sr0 for reading
    [0xb52042e8] dvdread demux error: DVDRead cannot open source: /dev/sr0
    [0xb5200618] main input error: open of `dvd:///dev/sr0' failed
```

When /dev/dvd/:

```
    libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 4.2.0
    libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.13 for DVD access
libdvdread: Can't stat /dev/dvd
Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu
libdvdread: Could not open /dev/dvd
libdvdnav: vm: failed to open/read the DVD
libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.13 for DVD access
libdvdread: Can't stat /dev/dvd
Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu
libdvdread: Could not open /dev/dvd
[0xb5203b68] dvdread demux error: DVDRead cannot open source: /dev/dvd
[0xb5204b18] main input error: open of `dvd:///dev/dvd' failed
```

sudo apt-get install dvd+rw-tools command gives this(DVD is in the drive)::
    INQUIRY:                [HL-DT-ST][DVDRAM GSA-T50N ][RT04]
    GET [CURRENT] CONFIGURATION:
    :-( no media mounted, exiting...

[ls -al /dev/ command gives this:

```
razem 4
drwxr-xr-x  16 root root        4080 gru 23 16:18 .
drwxr-xr-x  22 root root        4096 gru  7 10:35 ..
crw-------   1 root root     10, 235 gru 23 16:18 autofs
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root         620 gru 23 16:17 block
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root          80 gru 23 16:17 bsg
crw-------   1 root root     10, 234 gru 23 16:18 btrfs-control
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root          60 gru 23 16:17 bus
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root           3 gru 23 16:23 cdrom -> sr0
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root        3820 gru 23 16:18 char
crw-------   1 root root      5,   1 gru 23 16:18 console
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root          11 gru 23 16:17 core -> /proc/kcore
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root          60 gru 23 16:18 cpu
crw-------   1 root root     10,  60 gru 23 16:18 cpu_dma_latency
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root          80 gru 23 16:17 disk
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root          80 gru 23 16:18 dri
crw-------   1 root root     10,  61 gru 23 16:18 ecryptfs
crw-rw----   1 root video    29,   0 gru 23 16:18 fb0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root          13 gru 23 16:17 fd -> /proc/self/fd
crw-rw-rw-   1 root root      1,   7 gru 23 16:18 full
crw-rw-rw-   1 root root     10, 229 gru 23 16:18 fuse
crw-------   1 root root    251,   0 gru 23 16:18 fw0
crw-------   1 root root    250,   0 gru 23 16:18 hidraw0
crw-------   1 root root     10, 228 gru 23 16:18 hpet
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root          14 gru 23 16:17 .initramfs -> /run/initramfs
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root         380 gru 23 16:18 input
crw-r--r--   1 root root      1,  11 gru 23 16:18 kmsg
srw-rw-rw-   1 root root           0 gru 23 16:18 log
brw-rw----   1 root disk      7,   0 gru 23 16:18 loop0
brw-rw----   1 root disk      7,   1 gru 23 16:18 loop1
brw-rw----   1 root disk      7,   2 gru 23 16:18 loop2
brw-rw----   1 root disk      7,   3 gru 23 16:18 loop3
brw-rw----   1 root disk      7,   4 gru 23 16:18 loop4
brw-rw----   1 root disk      7,   5 gru 23 16:18 loop5
brw-rw----   1 root disk      7,   6 gru 23 16:18 loop6
brw-rw----   1 root disk      7,   7 gru 23 16:18 loop7
crw-------   1 root root     10, 237 gru 23 16:18 loop-control
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root          60 gru 23 16:17 mapper
crw-------   1 root root     10, 227 gru 23 16:18 mcelog
crw-r-----   1 root kmem      1,   1 gru 23 16:18 mem
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root          60 gru 23 16:17 net
crw-------   1 root root     10,  59 gru 23 16:18 network_latency
crw-------   1 root root     10,  58 gru 23 16:18 network_throughput
crw-rw-rw-   1 root root      1,   3 gru 23 16:18 null
crw-r-----   1 root kmem      1,   4 gru 23 16:18 port
crw-------   1 root root    108,   0 gru 23 16:18 ppp
crw-------   1 root root     10,   1 gru 23 16:18 psaux
crw-rw-rw-   1 root tty       5,   2 gru 23 16:26 ptmx
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root           0 gru 23 16:17 pts
brw-rw----   1 root disk      1,   0 gru 23 16:18 ram0
brw-rw----   1 root disk      1,   1 gru 23 16:18 ram1
brw-rw----   1 root disk      1,  10 gru 23 16:18 ram10
brw-rw----   1 root disk      1,  11 gru 23 16:18 ram11
brw-rw----   1 root disk      1,  12 gru 23 16:18 ram12
brw-rw----   1 root disk      1,  13 gru 23 16:18 ram13
brw-rw----   1 root disk      1,  14 gru 23 16:18 ram14
brw-rw----   1 root disk      1,  15 gru 23 16:18 ram15
brw-rw----   1 root disk      1,   2 gru 23 16:18 ram2
brw-rw----   1 root disk      1,   3 gru 23 16:18 ram3
brw-rw----   1 root disk      1,   4 gru 23 16:18 ram4
brw-rw----   1 root disk      1,   5 gru 23 16:18 ram5
brw-rw----   1 root disk      1,   6 gru 23 16:18 ram6
brw-rw----   1 root disk      1,   7 gru 23 16:18 ram7
brw-rw----   1 root disk      1,   8 gru 23 16:18 ram8
brw-rw----   1 root disk      1,   9 gru 23 16:18 ram9
crw-rw-rw-   1 root root      1,   8 gru 23 16:18 random
crw-rw-r--+  1 root root     10,  62 gru 23 16:18 rfkill
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root           4 gru 23 16:18 rtc -> rtc0
crw-------   1 root root    254,   0 gru 23 16:18 rtc0
brw-rw----   1 root disk      8,   0 gru 23 16:18 sda
brw-rw----   1 root disk      8,   1 gru 23 16:18 sda1
brw-rw----   1 root disk      8,   2 gru 23 16:18 sda2
brw-rw----   1 root disk      8,   5 gru 23 16:18 sda5
crw-rw----   1 root disk     21,   0 gru 23 16:18 sg0
crw-rw----+  1 root cdrom    21,   1 gru 23 16:18 sg1
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root           8 gru 23 16:18 shm -> /run/shm
crw-------   1 root root     10, 231 gru 23 16:18 snapshot
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root         280 gru 23 16:18 snd
brw-rw----+  1 root cdrom    11,   0 gru 23 16:23 sr0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root          15 gru 23 16:17 stderr -> /proc/self/fd/2
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root          15 gru 23 16:17 stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root          15 gru 23 16:17 stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
crw-rw-rw-   1 root tty       5,   0 gru 23 16:22 tty
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,   0 gru 23 16:18 tty0
crw-rw----   1 root tty       4,   1 gru 23 16:18 tty1
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  10 gru 23 16:18 tty10
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  11 gru 23 16:18 tty11
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  12 gru 23 16:18 tty12
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  13 gru 23 16:18 tty13
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  14 gru 23 16:18 tty14
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  15 gru 23 16:18 tty15
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  16 gru 23 16:18 tty16
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  17 gru 23 16:18 tty17
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  18 gru 23 16:18 tty18
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  19 gru 23 16:18 tty19
crw-rw----   1 root tty       4,   2 gru 23 16:18 tty2
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  20 gru 23 16:18 tty20
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  21 gru 23 16:18 tty21
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  22 gru 23 16:18 tty22
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  23 gru 23 16:18 tty23
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  24 gru 23 16:18 tty24
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  25 gru 23 16:18 tty25
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  26 gru 23 16:18 tty26
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  27 gru 23 16:18 tty27
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  28 gru 23 16:18 tty28
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  29 gru 23 16:18 tty29
crw-rw----   1 root tty       4,   3 gru 23 16:18 tty3
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  30 gru 23 16:18 tty30
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  31 gru 23 16:18 tty31
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  32 gru 23 16:18 tty32
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  33 gru 23 16:18 tty33
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  34 gru 23 16:18 tty34
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  35 gru 23 16:18 tty35
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  36 gru 23 16:18 tty36
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  37 gru 23 16:18 tty37
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  38 gru 23 16:18 tty38
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  39 gru 23 16:18 tty39
crw-rw----   1 root tty       4,   4 gru 23 16:18 tty4
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  40 gru 23 16:18 tty40
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  41 gru 23 16:18 tty41
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  42 gru 23 16:18 tty42
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  43 gru 23 16:18 tty43
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  44 gru 23 16:18 tty44
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  45 gru 23 16:18 tty45
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  46 gru 23 16:18 tty46
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  47 gru 23 16:18 tty47
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  48 gru 23 16:18 tty48
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  49 gru 23 16:18 tty49
crw-rw----   1 root tty       4,   5 gru 23 16:18 tty5
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  50 gru 23 16:18 tty50
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  51 gru 23 16:18 tty51
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  52 gru 23 16:18 tty52
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  53 gru 23 16:18 tty53
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  54 gru 23 16:18 tty54
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  55 gru 23 16:18 tty55
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  56 gru 23 16:18 tty56
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  57 gru 23 16:18 tty57
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  58 gru 23 16:18 tty58
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  59 gru 23 16:18 tty59
crw-rw----   1 root tty       4,   6 gru 23 16:18 tty6
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  60 gru 23 16:18 tty60
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  61 gru 23 16:18 tty61
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  62 gru 23 16:18 tty62
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,  63 gru 23 16:18 tty63
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,   7 gru 23 16:18 tty7
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,   8 gru 23 16:18 tty8
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,   9 gru 23 16:18 tty9
crw-------   1 root root      5,   3 gru 23 16:18 ttyprintk
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  64 gru 23 16:18 ttyS0
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  65 gru 23 16:18 ttyS1
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  74 gru 23 16:18 ttyS10
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  75 gru 23 16:18 ttyS11
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  76 gru 23 16:18 ttyS12
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  77 gru 23 16:18 ttyS13
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  78 gru 23 16:18 ttyS14
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  79 gru 23 16:18 ttyS15
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  80 gru 23 16:18 ttyS16
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  81 gru 23 16:18 ttyS17
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  82 gru 23 16:18 ttyS18
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  83 gru 23 16:18 ttyS19
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  66 gru 23 16:18 ttyS2
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  84 gru 23 16:18 ttyS20
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  85 gru 23 16:18 ttyS21
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  86 gru 23 16:18 ttyS22
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  87 gru 23 16:18 ttyS23
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  88 gru 23 16:18 ttyS24
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  89 gru 23 16:18 ttyS25
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  90 gru 23 16:18 ttyS26
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  91 gru 23 16:18 ttyS27
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  92 gru 23 16:18 ttyS28
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  93 gru 23 16:18 ttyS29
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  67 gru 23 16:18 ttyS3
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  94 gru 23 16:18 ttyS30
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  95 gru 23 16:18 ttyS31
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  68 gru 23 16:18 ttyS4
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  69 gru 23 16:18 ttyS5
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  70 gru 23 16:18 ttyS6
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  71 gru 23 16:18 ttyS7
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  72 gru 23 16:18 ttyS8
crw-rw----   1 root dialout   4,  73 gru 23 16:18 ttyS9
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root          60 gru 23 16:18 .udev
crw-------   1 root root     10, 239 gru 23 16:18 uhid
crw-------   1 root root     10, 223 gru 23 16:18 uinput
crw-rw-rw-   1 root root      1,   9 gru 23 16:18 urandom
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root          80 gru 23 16:18 v4l
crw-rw----   1 root tty       7,   0 gru 23 16:18 vcs
crw-rw----   1 root tty       7,   1 gru 23 16:18 vcs1
crw-rw----   1 root tty       7,   2 gru 23 16:18 vcs2
crw-rw----   1 root tty       7,   3 gru 23 16:18 vcs3
crw-rw----   1 root tty       7,   4 gru 23 16:18 vcs4
crw-rw----   1 root tty       7,   5 gru 23 16:18 vcs5
crw-rw----   1 root tty       7,   6 gru 23 16:18 vcs6
crw-rw----   1 root tty       7,   7 gru 23 16:18 vcs7
crw-rw----   1 root tty       7, 128 gru 23 16:18 vcsa
crw-rw----   1 root tty       7, 129 gru 23 16:18 vcsa1
crw-rw----   1 root tty       7, 130 gru 23 16:18 vcsa2
crw-rw----   1 root tty       7, 131 gru 23 16:18 vcsa3
crw-rw----   1 root tty       7, 132 gru 23 16:18 vcsa4
crw-rw----   1 root tty       7, 133 gru 23 16:18 vcsa5
crw-rw----   1 root tty       7, 134 gru 23 16:18 vcsa6
crw-rw----   1 root tty       7, 135 gru 23 16:18 vcsa7
crw-------   1 root root     10,  63 gru 23 16:18 vga_arbiter
crw-------   1 root root     10, 238 gru 23 16:18 vhost-net
crw-rw----+  1 root video    81,   0 gru 23 16:18 video0
crw-rw-rw-   1 root root      1,   5 gru 23 16:18 zero
```

wodim scanbus command:

```
wodim scanbus
wodim: No write mode specified.
wodim: Assuming -tao mode.
wodim: Future versions of wodim may have different drive dependent defaults.
wodim: Operation not permitted. Warning: Cannot raise RLIMIT_MEMLOCK limits.
Device was not specified. Trying to find an appropriate drive...
Detected CD-R drive: /dev/sr0
Using /dev/cdrom of unknown capabilities
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'HL-DT-ST'
Identification : 'DVDRAM GSA-T50N '
Revision       : 'RT04'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.
Using generic SCSI-3/mmc   CD-R/CD-RW driver (mmc_cdr).
Driver flags   : MMC-3 SWABAUDIO BURNFREE 
Supported modes: 
wodim: No such file or directory. Cannot open 'scanbus'.
```

Obviously, I am trying to play original DVDs from my region and the same region is set for the drive. I would really loved to watch some movies on my notebook. Could you help me?

Comment: what about another player besides vlc? If that works we can narrow it down to vlc problem.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it also doesn't work in SMP Player and in Ubuntu's default player. What's more, after inserting disc to drive window with "what to do with disc" also doesn't appear.

I followed steps from Help Ubuntu on my girlfriend notebook and it works, my notebook also played DVD's, but with upgrades lost this ability. I'm really confused :(

Comment: May be a specific bug in 13.10 then?

Comment: I encountered the same problem in 12.04 and it continued in present version. I wasn't using 11, but in 10.10 DVDs worked fine. Since than I haven't modified my notebook. 

Maybe its problem with encrypted DVDs?

Comment: Upgrade problem? I have no problems on 12.04 cleaninstall after following that guide. Try the guide again (the packages have changed, so the old probably didn't survive the upgrade. Or try following the steps on live DVD see if that can play, if so do a clean install

Comment: I installed 12.04 on clean HDD as the only OS. I followed all the steps listed on Help Ubuntu - DVDs movies weren't played. I've got alternatives for watching movies, so I left it as it was. This year I upgraded to 13.10, followed steps from Help Ubuntu (several times) and I still cannot play DVD movies.

Comment: Could you describe step by step what steps on help Ubuntu? Precise commands. I'm seeing the guide but I have no idea of what could be go wrong. **Edit your question and add the information**. BTW, since long ago, Ubuntu doesn't use the `/dev/dvd` file, but `/dev/cdrom` (yeah, even if it's a dvd).

Comment: Braiam, I specified my question. I tried playing with /dev/cdrom/ and the result is still the same - no ability to play DVDs.

Comment: I've just found that my DVD player is able to play DVD's made for only Region 2. Majority of my discs are Region 0 or Region 2+4, and those I would like to play at most. 

I've also bought a Fluendo DVD Player but I still can't play DVDs that I would like to.

Do you know any possible solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

If your drive is Region 2, then both Region 0 and Region 2+4 discs should work in theory. Region 0 discs are designed to be playable on drives of any region code, and discs with multiple region codes should work on drives of any of those region codes.

I would generally advise not to mess too much with the region code of the drive – chances are that your drive is set to region 0, and will thus accept discs from any region. (Some schemes exist to prevent discs from playing on a Region 0 drive, but they are not widely used and can be bypassed.) Setting a region code may limit your options for the future, as the region code can only be changed a limite number of times.

As others have noted already, the correct path to use is `/dev/sr0` or `/dev/cdrom`.

However, I have had a similar experience on 12.04. Certain DVDs would refuse to play, or stop playing some 15 minutes into the main title, while other DVDs would play with no issues.

The same DVDs that were giving me trouble would play without a glitch on a different computer (same OS but different hardware).

I don't have a complete solution – the problem seems to be related to the combination of computer (possibly just DVD drive) and DVD. However, I did figure out a workaround:

- Try playing the DVD on a different computer. (A live USB installation of Ubuntu may come in handy here.)
- When you have found a computer that will play the main title, use a file manager to copy the DVD contents to a USB drive or network share, in order to move to to the computer that refused the disc.
- To play the content of the DVD, start VLC and open the VIDEO_TS folder.

The copied folder will play even on the computer that refused the disc.